# Create a C++ object in shared library and return a pointer to Matlab with a wrapper

Tags: c++, matlab, shared-libraries

I want to use shared lib with Matlab, I've coded a simple function to create and return an object :

```
void *create_gmshMeshHandler(const char *filepath) {
    auto *mesh = new GmshMeshHandler(filepath);

    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "Pointer adress: %p\n", mesh);
    fclose(f);

    return mesh;
}
```

and in Matlab :

```
loadlibrary('libtestVP', 'testVP')
mesh = calllib('libtestVP', 'create_gmshMeshHandler', '/test/tetra.msh');
```

In file.txt : I can see the adress 0x7f528f56e380.

But in matlab, the pointer is empty

[image]

And I don't know why it does not work :/